# mediaelement.js - loading.gif transparency issue?

Tags: transparency, loading, gif, mediaelement.js

I noticed the transparent bg for the loading.gif doesn't work in Safari or Chrome (Mac). This is in my testing as well as the default video at http://mediaelementjs.com/

It just shows a square black box for the background on the loading gif.

Anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the css for this. You can get the fix here:

https://github.com/ccoulson/mediaelement/commit/866b1d8ac725ed0997a12232fb4446041a249415

I've written a blog post about the change, which you can read here:
http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/improving-the-mediaelement-js-loading-animation/